# Typo3 11 & imagemaps without adding extensions

Tags: typo3, imagemap

I've tried to add an imagemap to a typo3 11 site adding simple html code like:

```
<img src="/fileadmin/user_upload/mappa_web_resilienhnace.svg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Universita di Udine" title="Universita di Udine" href="https://www.uniud.it" coords="673,380,27" shape="circle">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Google" title="Google" href="https://www.google.it" coords="660,450,21" shape="circle">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Ancora Udine" title="Ancora Udine" href="https://www.uniud.it" coords="662,487,17" shape="circle">
</map>
```

I see the image but not the links inside it.
Is it something wrong in my workflow?
Do I need to add some extension to make it working?
I've searched StackOverflow for similar problems but it seems that the solutions are regarding only past versions of typo3 and involves the installation of some add-ons.

Thanks,
Fabiano

Comment: What is the generated html source code? Maybe there is something missing. How do you add this html code? With a content Element "HTML"? In an Fluid template?